# Multidimension PHP array parent tack value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been working on some code today where I got stuck at a little multidimensional array problem. First of all it's maybe handy to read some code I wrote to get a better view on the problem itself:

```
public function treeLeaves(array $elements, $parent = 0) {

$branch = array();

foreach($elements as $element) {

    $leaf = array('pageid'      => $element['pageid'],
                  'page_parent' => $element['page_parent'],
                  'label'       => ucfirst($element['page_print'][0]['print_title']),
                  'uri'         => $element['page_alias']);

    if($element['page_parent'] == $parent) {
        $children = $this->treeLeaves($elements, $leaf['pageid']);
        if($children) {
            foreach($children as $key => $child) {
                $leaf['pages'][] = $children[$key];
            }
        }
        $branch[] = $leaf;
    }
}

return $branch; }
```

For some reason I can't figure out how to glue the parent URI alias onto all the separate child URIs. The desired result I'm looking for should look something like this: http://pastebin.com/Eh9ExBjG

I hope some master can help me out here. I've been trying so many different stuff, but can't figure this thing out, even though I feel that it is relatively easy to solve.

Comment: what does `$elements` look like? Not toally clear if the uri needs to be created on the fly or children already have a url property. If can post it in json format would be great

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding charlie tfl. Every single leaf has its own 'alias' value and needs to be glued onto its children etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat simplified, but I think you would get the idea:

```
function treeLeaves($elements, $parent = 0, $baseUri = '/index') {
    $branch = array();
    foreach($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['page_parent'] == $parent) {
            $leaf = array(
                'uri'    => $baseUri . '/' . $element['page_alias'];
            );
            $leaf['pages'] = treeLeaves($elements, $element['pageid'], $leaf['uri']);
            $branch[] = $leaf;
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}
```

Comment: As I had expected, such a simpel solution. It did exactly where I was aiming for. Thanks for the support Peter! (as a fellow Dutchman concerns "Enorm bedankt Peter!")

Comment: Thanks for the dutch translation ;)